# importing csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I want to import CSV files in a python script. Column and row numbers are not fixed , first row contains name of the variables and next rows are values of those variables. 
I am new to Python, any help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service. Please show your efforts and some sample csvs.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include an example of your input, and also what output you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
csv_reader = csv.reader(open(path_file + filename, 'rb'))
fields = []
data = []
for i, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
    if i < 1:
        item = str(row[0]).split(';')
        for elem in item:
            fields.append(elem)
    else:
        obj_val = {}
        items = str(row[0]).decode(codes).split(';')
        for i, item in enumerate(items):
            obj_val[fields[i]] = item
        data.append(obj_val)
```

- fields - field
- data - rows from csv

Comment: Down voted because you're doing a lot of work to simply replicate `csv.DictReader`

Comment: @donkopotamus. Sorry but this option does not work for me, so use this.

Comment: I upvoted, bcuz atleast he tried in a different way @donkopotamus

Answer (score 0):

So as not to just *give out* a homework answer, but to still point you in the right direction; import the CSV module. If you're using Python 3.5 here's the [link](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) to the doc. If you want to see the doc for a different version, use the drop-down on the top-left of the page to select it.

Anyway...

You'll want to open the CSV file like you would any other, then use the CSV module to read the content. Iterating over each row in the file will return you a list of strings; which are the contents of that row.

For example:

```
['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Header 3'...]
['A1', 'A2', 'A3'...]
['B1', 'B2', 'B3'...]
['C1', 'C2', 'C3'...]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, at the top of the code do `import csv`

After that you need to set a variable name; this is so you can open the CSV file. For example, `data=open('CSV name', 'rt')` You will need to fill in where it says CSV name. That's how you open it.

To read a CSV file, you set another variable. For example, `data2=csv.reader(data)`